# How to create a Route in Laravel to this scenario?

Tags: laravel, routes

The basic idea is to work like a sub-domain architecture, but the user account will come after website's name.

I have a web service that is called **myService.com**.
I will have users like Paul, Anne, Jhon.
I want Laravel to be able to create home pages for Paul, Anne and Jhon like this:

1. **myService.com**/Paul = > Should redirects to Paul home page
2. **myService.com**/Anne = > Should redirects to Anne home page
3. **myService.com**/Jhon = > Should redirects to Jhon home page

but **myService.com** has its own home page and others pages too. I do like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');//myService.com HOME page
});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'videos'], function (){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "all videos";
    });
    Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
        return "Video => $id";
    });

});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'articles'], function (){

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return "all articles";
        });
        Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
            return "Article => $id";
        });
 });
```

For the users I will have almost the same URL structure:

```
myService.com/Paul
myService.com/Paul/videos
myService.com/Paul/videos/id
myService.com/Paul/articles
myService.com/Paul/articles/id

myService.com/Paul2
myService.com/Paul2/videos
myService.com/Paul2/videos/id
myService.com/Paul2/articles
myService.com/Paul2/articles/id
```

Since I will have unlimited users account I dont know how to design the Route structure for this scenario.

Is It should be like this?

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'account'], function (){

    Route::get('/', function ($account) {
        return "user $account home page";//Ex myService.com/Paul
    });

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'videos'], function (){
        Route::get('/', function () {
           return "user account - all videos";//Ex myService.com/Paul/videos
        });

        Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
           return "user account video => $id";//Ex myService.com/Paul/videos/id
        });
    });

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'articles'], function (){
        Route::get('/', function () {
           return "user account - all articles";//Ex myService.com/Paul/articles
        });

        Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
           return "user account articles => $id";//Ex myService.com/Paul/articles/id
        });
    });

});
```

This is what I did so far, but I dont know if it is a good approach. It is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define that group at the end of your routes so the other routes will have precedence. Then you can use slug for username (or whatever you are using)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{username}'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'videos'], function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

But this groupe is more likely to try and pick up all your `404`. Maybe you can add extra constraint

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{username}'], function(){
    ...
})->where('username', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

Comment: Hi Eddy,  I did like this `Route::group(['prefix'=>'{account}'], function (){ ... ` and at the end ` ... })->where('account', '[A-Za-z]+');` But the code only works when I remove the filter where.  Any idea?

Comment: Hum, my guess is that, it doesn't work with route groups I think. Perhaps you should apply it to the first route and see if it works.